# How to share platform dependent python packages using source control?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

Currently we keep project related python packages in a subversion directory, so when someone adds or removes one it will directly be available to others.

Still, this method works well with Python packages that are not platform dependent.

Still I do have quite a few that are platform dependent and worse, when you install them using `easy_install` they will need a compiler to produce the `.egg` file.

I had to mention that the package maintainers are not providing binaries for these modules, so I need to compile it manually. I've tried to add the `.egg` file to the shared directory but python doesn't pick it up by default.

**While in the entire team only a few have compilers, how can we share the packages in an easy way?**

To make the problem even more complex, I had to specify that even if in 99% of the code is run on the same platform (Windows) with the same version of Python (2.5), we still have few scripts that are to be executed on another platform (Linux).